# Can I enrich Microdata format with more non-Microdata data without affecting its functionality?

Tags: html5, microdata

This is the normal formatting for Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div itemprop="name">some text</div>
<div itemprop="description">some description</div>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Rosary Arms 12</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">90210</span> 
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Beverly Hills</span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">San Fransisco</span> 
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when a users searches for all businesses in San Fransisco, I want to format each result with this Microdata (I'm assuming this is allowed btw and not that Google only accepts 1 Microdata 'instance' on a page).

But in the search result of 1 result I have more data than is currently needed for Microdata. For example, I have 3 images per search result, rates of this business, opening hours and much more.
Now I was wondering if I can just place this extra data within this microdata without affecting its functionality, for example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div itemprop="name">some text</div>
<div class="businesspreviewthumbs">
    <img src="/images/1.png" />
    <img src="/images/2.png" />
    <img src="/images/3.png" />
</div>
<div class="rates">
    <span>Hourrate: $120</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="description">some description</div>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Rosary Arms 12</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">90210</span> 
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Beverly Hills</span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">San Fransisco</span> 
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">USA</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Opening hours:<br/>
        Monday-Friday: 8AM - 6PM<br/>
        Saturday: 10AM - 5PM<br/>
        Sunday:Closed<br/>
        </p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  Parsers only look for the elements not the existence of additional classes or attributes.

Go nuts!

Comment: Thank you. And it's allowed to have a microdata part multiple times on the same page?